# Interface builder connections cause crash in tab bar application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, iboutlet

for exercise I'm trying to develop a simple iPhone application based on a tab bar from scratch, but I had some problem..
I've follow up these steps:  http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Creating_an_iPhone_Multiview_Application_using_the_Tab_Bar

The app loads correctly the three views until there's no connection within; if I connect any outlets or action to a label or button of the subviews, the app crash.

For example, my firstView.h contains:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@interface firstView : UIViewController {
IBOutlet UILabel *resultLabel;
}

-(IBAction)randomizeAction;

@property (nonatomic , retain) IBOutlet UILabel *resultLabel;


@end
```

and the firstView.m

```
-(IBAction)randomizeAction:(id)sender
{
//NSInteger rand = arc4random() % 75;
//resultLabel.text = [ [NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Random integer: @%",rand];
UIAlertView *alert = [ [UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Yeah!" message:@"Yeah" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles:nil ];
[alert show];
[alert release];

}
```

If I connect a label to the resultOutlet or a button to the "randomizeAction" method, the app crash when I switch to the related views..
Where is the mistake?

Answer (score 1):

in .h file you declare a property to be IBOutlet twice. As I don't think this causes the problem but it's just unnecessary. Also you declared `randomizeAction` in the .h file wihout the parameter and you implemented it with a parameter.

Your code should look like this:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface firstView : UIViewController {
   UILabel *resultLabel;
}
@property (nonatomic , retain) IBOutlet UILabel *resultLabel;

-(IBAction)randomizeAction:(id)sender;

@end
```

and the firstView.m

```
-(IBAction)randomizeAction:(id)sender
{
   //do stuff
}
```

Comment: thanks, I fixed the declaration, but seems not solve the problem.. Now the app loads the view, but when I press the button, causes a crash with: "terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'". I also try to replace the method content with a simple NSLog, but nothing changed

Comment: Pls, paste the entire stacktrace that comes with the exception.

Comment: 2011-08-07 16:00:35.609 Profile[2320:207] -[UIViewController randomizeAction:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4b3d630
2011-08-07 16:00:35.613 Profile[2320:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIViewController randomizeAction:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4b3d630'

Comment: You set the NIB Name to `firstView` but did not set the Class to `firstView` in the identity pane.

Answer (score 0):

From that error message it looks like your view controller isn't hooked up properly in Interface Builder. Are you sure your view controller (File's Owner in IB) is identified as an instance of firstView? Check what class it is in the Identity Inspector in XCode.

Also it would be helpful if you can show the code where your view controller is declared and created (most likely in the App Delegate).

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure, but I think you have to change this:

```
@interface DetailViewController : UIViewController
```

To:

```
@interface firstView : UIViewController
```

Comment: ...? I don't understand? Did you solve your problem yourself?

Comment: no I didn't solve the problem yet.. I made a typo here in the post, but in my code the class declaration is correct.. I'll edit also there..